# How do I enable addons in google container engine?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I have been working on this for quite some time now, but google container engine has some missing documentation on installing addons.

First I thought I create my addons as `yml` files and install them into the `kube-system` namespace.

But the addon-manager apparently removes everything from the `kube-system` namespace that in its opinion does not belong there.

**How do I add any kubernetes addon to my google container engine cluster?**

For example I would like to install:

- [**cluster-monitoring** (heapster, influxdb, grafana addon)](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/cluster/addons/cluster-monitoring)

Answer (score 0):

The add-on manager is removing everything from the `kube-system` namespace that has the label `addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode: Reconcile` which doesn't exist in a "source of truth" location. Since your resources aren't in the source of truth, they get removed.

You can remove that label and the add-on manager should leave your deployments alone. But I'd recommend running them in a different namespace instead.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. Do you know how to edit the source of truth at google compute engine?
Ideally these addons should be managed by the addon manager as well. Another problem I am facing when running these addons in a separate namespace is, that I would need to run `heapster` twice. One is already running in the `kube-system` namespace.

Comment: You cannot edit the source of truth on GKE directly. You can use the GKE API to modify parts of it (enable/disable some of the addons).

Comment: If you turn off enough GKE addons then heapster won't run in the kube-system namespace and you will end up running only your copy of it. I think it's required for a number of GKE addons though, so you may have to turn off most/all of the GKE addons for it to disappear.